При <условие 1> и <условие 2> <что-то этакое> выполняется автоматически

При <условие 1> и <условие 2> <что-то этакое> выполняется автоматически.

Пример из жизни:

При brew upgrade <формула> и brew upgrade brew update выполняется автоматически.

Подскажите пожалуйста, нужна ли после второго условия запятая, и почему.
